# How to change the number of nodes of a dense layer in an existing keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can I change the number of nodes of a layer in a keras model?

One approach i've tried is to use keras functional API to make a deep clone of the layer with the desired changes, for example:

```
config = layer.get_config()
units = config['units']
config['units'] = units + 1 # Add one node

clone = layer.from_config(config)
x = clone(layer.input)

outbound_layer = layer.outbound_nodes[0].outbound_layer
outbound_layer_clone = outbound_layer.from_config(outbound_layer.get_config())
outbound_layer_clone(x)
```

But is there a better way to approach this?